# What is the limiting distribution of $Z_n = \frac{X_1 X_2 + X_3 X_4 + \cdots + X_{2n-1} X_{2n}}{\sqrt{n}}$

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Hope this isn't a duplicate.

Let $ X_1,X_2, \ldots$  be iid RVs with mean $0$, variance $1$ and $E{X_i}^4 < \infty , \forall i \in \Bbb N$. So I was trying to find the limiting distribution of $$Z_n = \frac{X_1 X_2 + X_3 X_4 + \cdots + X_{2n-1} X_{2n}}{\sqrt{n}}.$$

I have recently learned Weak Law Of Large Numbers, Strong Law Of Large Numbers and Central Limit Theorem but currently have no idea how to approach the problem. Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: Define $Y_j := X_{2j-1}X_{2j}$.  Then you have $$Z_n = \frac{Y_1 + \cdots +Y_n}{\sqrt{n}}.$$

What is the limiting distribution now?  (Hover below for a more full answer)

> The central limit theorem tells us that this is asymptotically normal, you just have to find the mean and variance.  We know that $E[Y] = E[X]E[X] = 0$ and $E[Y^2] = E[X^2]E[X^2] = 1$, implying that $Z_n$ is asymptotically a standard normal.

Comment: Thanks for such an explanatory answer.

Comment: A complete proof should mention that, rather crucially, $(Y_j)$ is independent.

Comment: @Did, Yes of course; additionally, they're identically distributed.